# How to refresh ngTable without losing focus when we reload data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using [ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) directive for displaying properties of the network interfaces. Based on example #22 [Inline edit example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/22) I've built a table where data is periodically fetched from a web-service (for each network interface I'm displaying changes of tx, rx counters). Fetching is done by the $timer service which calls reload() function on the ngTableParams object. Unfortunately each time when I type text, the input element is losing his focus because the whole table is rerendered. Is there any opportunity to refresh only those cells for which tx, rx counters are changing?

Comment: Can you just stop the timer while editing(:focus) and turn it back on when you're done(:blur)?

Comment: @Dylan thanks for reply. I think about your solution, but I've already found solution to my problem. I've added `track by` in repeat_expression for the ng-repeat directive, so I have now `ng-repeat="networkInterface in networkInterfaces track by networkInterface.name"` and it works.